# function not passed with required variable (Expo/React Native)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to let allow the button to navigate me to the Home Screen after pressing, but it seems like the function does not have the variable 'navigation', how do I pass this variable to the function? Below is my code snippet

```
const LoggedInPage = props => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.loggedin}>Welcome: {props.name}</Text>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: props.photoUrl }} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button2} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get Started!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you show the props by console.log(this.props) ?

Comment: I am fairly new and very sorry that I don't know how to do that, can you provide the lines of code and where to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no this binding in functional component; you can use useNavigation hook to get the navigation prop.

Code:

```
const LoggedInPage = ({ name, photoUrl }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.loggedin}>Welcome: {name}</Text>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: photoUrl }} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button2} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get Started!</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I encountered a Component Exception error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?